# Call recording using twilio in iOS application

Tags: ios, twilio, phone-call, recording

We are creating a recording application in iOS, in that app we want to provide a functionality to record a call. For calling from the application to phone we are using twilio iOS SDK.

How call can be recorded using twilio iOS SDK.

We want that if user enable recording into app, then call should get record, if recording is off then it should not get record.

Backend technology used by us for managing twiml is PHP.

Code for for making a call we have written a below code:
    -(void)callsetup:(NSString*)dialnumber{
        NSString *CallerID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:PRPhoneNumber];
        self.callViewController.mainText = dialnumber;
        [PKTPhone sharedPhone].callerId = CallerID;
        [[PKTPhone sharedPhone] call:dialnumber];
    }

```
///*** PKTPhone class next working***
-(void)call:(NSString *)callee
{
    [self call:callee withParams:nil];
}

- (void)call:(NSString *)callee withParams:(NSDictionary *)params
{

     reciverID = callee;



    if (!(self.phoneDevice && self.capabilityToken)) {
        NSLog(@"Error: You must set PKTPhone's capability token before you make a call");
        return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *connectParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:params];
    if (callee.length)
        connectParams[@"callee"] = callee;
    if (self.callerId.length)
        connectParams[@"callerId"] = self.callerId;

     connectParams[@"recording"] = @true;

    self.activeConnection = [self.phoneDevice connect:connectParams delegate:self];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callStartedWithParams:incoming:)]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.delegate callStartedWithParams:connectParams incoming:NO];
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code written by us at server end in php:

```
$from     = $_REQUEST['From'];
$callee   = $_REQUEST['callee'];
$callerId = $_REQUEST['callerId'];
$digits   = $_REQUEST['Digits'];

$record = (isset($_REQUEST["recording"]) && $_REQUEST["recording"] == true) ? " record='record-from-answer'" : '';
if (isset($digits) && !$callee) {
    $callee = $_REQUEST[$digits];
}


$response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial'.$record.' callerId="'.$callerId.'">
<Number url="http://ourserverurl.net/phoneRecorder/twilio/twilio-client-server-master/notification.php">'.$callee.'</Number>
</Dial>
</Response>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use your `connectParams` to [pass parameters to the TwiML application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/tcdevice#parameters). Any parameter you pass will be passed on to your PHP application. So, you could add a parameter to signify whether your are recording or not and then produce the TwiML that will or will not record.

For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *connectParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:params];
    if (callee.length)
        connectParams[@"callee"] = callee;
    if (self.callerId.length)
        connectParams[@"callerId"] = self.callerId;
    if (self.recording)
        connectParams[@"recording"] = @true;
```

Then in your PHP:

```
<?php 

$recording = isset($_REQUEST["recording"]);

$response = "<Response>"
$response .= "<Dial";
if ($recording) {
  $response .= " record='record-from-answer'";
}
$response .= "><Number>+15551234567</Number></Dial></Response>";

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $response;
```

Of course, you are probably setting other values too, that's an example of getting the recording parameter and [using it with TwiML to record the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record).

Comment: We have written the same code at our server end in php, but we are not getting recording param in our php code. At iOS end we have written the same code and initiated the call. Is there any other settings to be done other then mentioned in the solution provided by you.

Comment: We are receiving callee and callerId, but recording parameter is not received in php.

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the function that makes the call using those parameters? I need to see a bit more in order to help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Objective-C side of things, though the PHP will help.

Comment: Ah, ok. So, to be honest I'm not a strong PHP developer. Can you see if `$_REQUEST["recording"]` is set and see what it is set to? I don't know if it will come across as a string rather than the boolean (though I am suspecting it may be a string, so your comparison with `true` may not work).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Customer Support here.

I am not seeing a parameter 'recording' in the HTTP request to your web app.  That implies it is not being sent by the iOS app.

-- Rob

Comment: Can i use twillio to make an iOS application that records phone calls? if yes. can you please guide me into right direction ? is backend server also needed. need a - z details on it please